# Partition the real line into an uncountable number of half-open intervals?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

It recently occurred to me that I've never seen a scheme to partition the real line into an **uncountable** number of half-open intervals. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: No. The rationals are dense in IR.

Comment: What do you mean by IR?

Comment: The real line of course. And yes, the rationals are countable.

Comment: I know it as $\mathbb{R}$. Anyway, the rationals are countable.

Comment: @ted: Yes, and every one of your half open intervals will contain a rational. So you cannot have uncountably many disjoint half open intervals.

Comment: As for notation, @amsmath is using ASCII art.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that's very cool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you mean *distinct* half-open intervals; otherwise, the problem is trivial. It is not possible; any such interval will have a rational number, and there are only countably many rational numbers.

Comment: Partitions are distinct.

Comment: @amsmath Sorry, I don't follow. I credited jose with providing the answer. I would have credited you but there is no way to credit a commenter. Regarding my comment that partitions are distinct, text does not convey affect very well, I was just letting jose that this is covered in the phrasing of the question.

Comment: @ted Fair enough. The thing is that your very short comments to hints and answers appear harsh and disrespectful to the ones that help. Well, at least to me. You are completely right with saying that partitions are distinct, but this might sound for José like: "Read my post, idiot. I wrote these are partitions". Also in the comments you should at least have thought a minute (not a second) about what I was writing instead of doubting that it's helpful from the scratch. Instead you seemed to wanna say to me that you know stuff better. That's not the way you deal with helpers in my opinion.

Comment: @amsmath Many apologies if that's the way it appeared. For the record, I think everybody here is smarter than me. That's why I post questions :-)

Comment: Alright, ted. Thank you for getting back to me.